# Issue while rendering header in footer in custom build package on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am trying to create a node package with simple html elements package name is [fmg_test_header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fmg_test_header).

I have only simples files

```
header.jsx
index.js
package.json
```

**header.js**

```
function Header() {
   return "<h1>Head</h1>";
}
export default Header;
```

**index.js**

```
const Header = require('./header');

module.exports = Header;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "fmg_test_header",
  "version": "1.1.8",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I am importing the same and trying to render it in React JS

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Header from 'fmg_test_header';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But  this is always rending HTML Tags

[image]

How can i render the `Head` without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

header.js

```
function Header() {
   return <h1>Head</h1>;
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: I have tried, the result is same

Comment: create react app with vite, then you can use components